# Certbot wildcard with apache but none of the listed DNS providers

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt, certbot

On the official certbot documentation for apache (https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache.html), it says you should do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-dns-<PLUGIN>
```

However, when I start typing that and then double TAB after `dns`, I only get the following options:

```
python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare    python3-certbot-dns-dnsimple      python3-certbot-dns-rfc2136       
python3-certbot-dns-digitalocean  python3-certbot-dns-google        python3-certbot-dns-route53
```

If you have a different DNS provider, is it still possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the manual plugin, if your dns provider is not listed.
Just checkout the documentation at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual